# How to add expiry date when generating Bouncy Castle PGP key pair?

Tags: java, cryptography, bouncycastle

I was following https://bouncycastle-pgp-cookbook.blogspot.com/ to generate the PGP key pair. It worked well with pub and private key files generated. But when I look at the pub key, it does not have expiry date. I set key expiration time on PGPSignatureSubpacketGenerator. `signhashgen.setKeyExpirationTime(true, 864000);`

Answer (score 2):

It took me a few hours to figure out the answer. Since I have two subpackets in the PGPKeyPair, I have to set expiration date on both subpackets. Then the expiration date will show in certificate and subkey details as shown in the screenshot.
[image: certificate details]
[image: subkeys details]

Comment: Typically one will be the primary, the other a sub key. As indicated by the primary column in the last screenshot.